# tesseract ChoiceIterator confidence threshold

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use tesseract (3.03) ChoiceIterator to list possible alternatives of each character in a serial number. For some characters it seems to be working fine:

```
symbol 3, conf: 82.660316   
   - 3 conf: 82.660316
   - B conf: 74.598289
   - S conf: 74.530128
```

For other characters it's not working (ie. it doesn't return any alternatives):

```
symbol I, conf: 90.924942
```

Now, I find it hard to believe that "I" is not easy to be confused with "1" (actually in my case the character is "1" not "I"). I'm guessing that tesseract must be discarding alternatives on the basis of their low confidence (ie. confidence below some threshold?) but I'm unable to find any suitable option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many hours of digging into Tesseract code I've finally found it - the parameter name is "matcher_bad_match_pad" and it tells Tesseract what is the cut-off threshold relative to the highest confidence prediction for a character. So, in my example:

```
symbol I, conf: 90.924942
```

if "matcher_bad_match_pad" is set to 0.20 and confidence for "1" is say 0.70, it will be rejected. Fixed it like this:

```
tesseract.SetVariable("matcher_bad_match_pad", "0.25");
```